# CodeIgniter flash message disappears quickly

Tags: codeigniter

am using codeigniter to redirect to a certain page with some flash message. the problem is that the flash message appears in the new page briefly, about a sec before disappearing. I need it to stay on the new page as log as it's not refreshed.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#tempdata

Comment: cool. what i was looking for exact. thanks